# Passport not logging in

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am using Passport for user authentication for with Local Strategy. I can't login and yet I get no error message. I even set up flash messaging but I get nothing when I try to login.

Here's my project tree

Project Folder:.
│   -index.js
│   -package.json
│
├───config
│       db.js
│       passport.js
│
├───controllers
│       accounts.js 
│
├───models
│       institution.js
│       user.js
│
├───routes
│       accounts.js
│       user.js

/config/passport:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


module.exports = function (passport) {
  //  Configure Passport authentication
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
          if (err) throw error;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(
              null,
              false,
              { message: "Incorrect Username or password" }
            );
          }
        })
      });
    })
  );
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing');
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
}
```

/controllers/accounsts:

```
const handleLogin = function handleLogin (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/accounts/login',
    failureFlash: true
  }) (req, res, next);
}
```

/routes/accounts:

```
router.post('/login', accounts.handleLogin);
```

index.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(expressValidator());


app.use(cookieParser('keyboard cat'));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.use(flash());

app.use(function (req, res, next){
  res.locals.messages = messages(req, res);
  next();
});


app. use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Login keeps redirecting to the failure redirect route and doesn't display the failure message.

How do I fix this

Comment: It's hard to know what has happens.You can add some debug logs in the callback of 'User.findOne'

Comment: I added a bunch of console.log but got nothing. The console.log within the verify callback didn't fire at all

Comment: You can have a reference on https://github.com/bradtraversy/loginapp. Have a compare, maybe you can know the root cause.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

In index.js
decalre " require('./config/passport')(passport); "this first, then this

"app. use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());"

Under passport.js

```js
  passport.use(
       new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(request, email, password, done) {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                User.findOne({ username }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    } else if (!users.length) {
                        return done(null, false, { errorUsername: "user doesnt exist" });
                    } else {

                        var user = users[0];
                        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, 
 res) {
                            if (res) {

                                return done(null, user);
                            } else {
                                return done(null, false);
                            }
                        });
                        
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            });
        })
);
```